# The error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, this error occurs:

> The object reference is not set to the instance of an object.

It gives the error on the *foreach* line. Why is this happening?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="kitap">

        <img src="~/Content/images/sucveceza.png">
        <p>@item.KonuBaslik</p>
        <a href="">

        </a>
        }

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Because `Model` is `null` (you did not pass a model to the view)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons

1. You have not passed model from controller.
2. you passed model but value is null.